# Visual Studio Code installation error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-1.0

I am trying to install  .NET Core SDK for Windows. I have already installed Visual Studio Code and the C# extension for VSCode.
 But while installing .NET Core SDK for Windows I am getting the following error:

> 0x80070490 Element not found.

I cannot understand much when I examine the log file.

This error is happening at the beginning of the installation(while installing Microsoft visual C++ 2015 Redistributable).

Comment: A thin line of error message is useless. You should post enough lines around the error from the installation log file.

Comment: Ok. I will post the lines from th log file.